# Rosetta Stone Installation

Tags: installation

I am trying to install a Rosettastone language and not having much luck. Ny help out there would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Meryl

Answer (score 1):

People have had mixed results getting Rosetta Stone to run under [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).  See [Rosetta Stone under Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1867).

I would recommend that you run it under VM.  You can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).  VirtualBox is available in Ubuntu Apps, to install click [**VirtualBox** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/virtualbox-qt/)